# HTML table with built-in calculator for money

Tags: html, html-table, calculator

I'm trying to make a table where you can put the number of bills you have of a certain bill type and get the cash amount back but I'm new to HTML and have no idea how to do multiplication inside HTML. How do I make it so that someone can type 3 in one box and it output 3 times 100 in another box? like 3 times 100 for 100s 3 times 50 for 50s etc. Here's my code, please help

[image: My Shit Code]

I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't let me post my code, it just says it's not formatted properly as code. The attached image above is a screenshot of my code, I want to be able to input the number of bills into the middle colum and the corresponding cash amount to be displayed in the right colum

Comment: pictures don't help.  show actual code. try creating a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `contenteditable` attribute simply use a semantic `input` and `output`.

Then use JS to listen to `change` events of inputs and then calculate the output in JS.

You can simplify (make the code shorter) in JS with the usage of an `array of objects` and `for`-loop. I guess that this way it is easier to understand for you:

```js
// eventListener to listen to change Events of the inputs
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // getting the value of the inputs
    let usd_100 = +document.querySelector('#usd-100').value,
        usd_50  = +document.querySelector('#usd-50').value,
        usd_25  = +document.querySelector('#usd-25').value,
        usd_10  = +document.querySelector('#usd-10').value,
        usd_5   = +document.querySelector('#usd-5').value,
        usd_1   = +document.querySelector('#usd-1').value;
    
    // calculating the sum of each row
    let sum_usd_100 = usd_100 * 100,
        sum_usd_50  = usd_50 * 50,
        sum_usd_25  = usd_25 * 25,
        sum_usd_10  = usd_10 * 10,
        sum_usd_5   = usd_5 * 5,
        sum_usd_1   = usd_1 * 1;
    
    // outputting the sum of each row
    document.querySelector('output[for="usd-100"]').value = sum_usd_100;
    document.querySelector('output[for="usd-50"]').value = sum_usd_50;
    document.querySelector('output[for="usd-25"]').value = sum_usd_25;
    document.querySelector('output[for="usd-10"]').value = sum_usd_10;
    document.querySelector('output[for="usd-5"]').value = sum_usd_5;
    document.querySelector('output[for="usd-1"]').value = sum_usd_1;
    
    // getting the total sum of the entire column
    document.querySelector('#sum-total').value = sum_usd_100 + sum_usd_50 + sum_usd_25 + sum_usd_10 + sum_usd_5 + sum_usd_1;
  })
)
```

```css
/*for styling purpose only */
td:last-child,
input {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bill Type</th>
    <th>Amount of Bills</th>
    <th>Cash Amount of Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-100">100$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-100" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-100">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-50">50$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-50" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-50">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-25">25$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-25" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-25">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-10">10$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-10" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-10">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-5">5$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-5" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-5">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-1">1$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-1" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-1">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum</td>
    <td><output for="usd-100 usd-50 usd-25 usd-10 usd-5 usd-1" id="sum-total">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want the "harder" but shorter solution use an `array of object`:

```js
// eventListener to listen to change Events of the inputs
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    let money = [ { bill: 100, amount: 0, sum: 0, },
                  { bill: 50, amount: 0, sum: 0, },
                  { bill: 25, amount: 0, sum: 0, },
                  { bill: 10, amount: 0, sum: 0, },
                  { bill: 5, amount: 0, sum: 0, },
                  { bill: 1, amount: 0, sum: 0, } ];
                    
    // getting the data of input
    for (let i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
      money[i].amount = +document.querySelector(`#usd-${money[i].bill}`).value;
    };
    
    // calculating the sum of each row
    for (let i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
      money[i].sum = money[i].bill * money[i].amount;
    };
    
    // outputting the sum of each row
    for (let i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
      document.querySelector(`output[for="usd-${money[i].bill}"]`).value = money[i].sum;
    };
    
    // outputting the total 
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
      sum += money[i].sum;
    };
    document.querySelector('#sum-total').value = sum;
  })
)
```

```css
/*for styling purpose only */
td:last-child,
input {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bill Type</th>
    <th>Amount of Bills</th>
    <th>Cash Amount of Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-100">100$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-100" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-100">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-50">50$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-50" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-50">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-25">25$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-25" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-25">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-10">10$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-10" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-10">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-5">5$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-5" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-5">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="usd-1">1$</label></td>
    <td><input id="usd-1" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">$</td>
    <td><output for="usd-1">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum</td>
    <td><output for="usd-100 usd-50 usd-25 usd-10" id="sum-total">0</output>$</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```